# BigQuery DML on partitioned table with nested required fields in nullable records

Tags: google-bigquery, atomic, dml

We've got a data lake in BigQuery, which is a daily partitioned table (with several TBs of data / day). The table should have a unique identifier based on a composite key consisting of multiple fields.

Every now and then, we have to do modifications to historical data, which we approached using [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax). The goal of the modification, is to have an easy way of modifying the data, that is cost efficient and **atomic**.

The challenge arises, due to the schema that our table has. I'll illustrate using an example. Note that this table is not partitioned, though that should not matter for the illustration, only for the costs. The final solution should leverage the fact that the table is partitioned.

Assume we have the a table, with the following schema:

[image: Table schema]

And the following data:

[image: Table data]

Let's say that `fruit.color` should be changed with a DML statement. Note the fact, that `fruit` is a **nullable** record, and `fruit.type` is **required**.

The DML can be executed using either an `UPDATE` or a `MERGE` query.

**Using `UPDATE`**

```sql
#standardSQL
UPDATE `test_dataset.fruity_table`
SET
  fruit.color = 'unknown'
WHERE id in ('1', '2')
```

Unfortunately, the `UPDATE` statement, does not have the option to conditionally update a field. This is required, since the query above fails with `Required field fruit.type cannot be null; error in writing field fruit`. It is possible to use a subquery for this, but in our schema, required fields in nullable records are very common. Hence, we'd have to do multiple update statements, which would break the atomic requirement.

**Using `MERGE`**

```sql
#standardSQL
MERGE `test_dataset.fruity_table` t
USING `test_dataset.fruity_table` s
ON t.id = s.id
WHEN MATCHED AND t.fruit IS NOT NULL
 THEN UPDATE SET fruit.color = 'unknown'
WHEN MATCHED AND t.fruit IS NULL
 THEN -- do nothing, maybe update some other fields that need to be changed
```

For the `MERGE` statement, we unfortunately have to deal with the fact that there are duplicates in the BigQuery table. That is something a `MERGE` statement cannot handle. It fails with `UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row`.

As you can see, we have the need for the granularity of the `MERGE` query, with the flexibility of the `UPDATE` query. If `MERGE` would just update all the records that are matched, this would work.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Maybe a totally different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UPDATE, but rather than SET'ing fruit.color, SET fruit - similar to how you do it in MERGE. You just need to express options you have in MERGE as a single expression setting fruit, either to NULL or something with non-NULL required field:

```
update test_dataset.fruity_table
SET fruit = IF(fruit IS NOT NULL, STRUCT('unknown', fruit.type), NULL) 
where id = '3'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael! The thing however is, that I don't want to put any dummy data in the table. I'll update the query of the merge, since this was unclear. I don't want to do anything with the `fruit.color` if `fruit` is null.

Comment: I've updated the `MERGE` query. Is it clear now that there might be some other fields that do need to be changed? I wanted to keep the MVP as small as possible to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I think you can still use this approach, just change expression computing fruit. It has to produce either NULL struct or something with non-NULL type, there is no way around it since type is required. E.g.: 
SET fruit = IF(fruit IS NOT NULL, STRUCT('unknown', fruit.type), NULL)

Comment: Combining your comment and the update query above, this seems to be what I'm looking for! I'll also test it out for a more complicated use case to verify. Could you update your original post with the input from the comment as well? Then it's complete when I accept the answer :)